# How to implement historical data with this EERD?

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd, data, data-loss

I am looking for a way to implement historical data with the following EERD (what I have tried, below the image):
[image: Entity Relationship Diagram]

### What have I tried?

- Temporal tables

> Didn't work because I use MySQL and it has no native support. And also isn't the best solution (when doing natively) because then I am fixed to one database provider.

- History tables

> This is a valid option but some things won't work.
> For example, I change the supplier name, a new record will be added to SupplierHistory table, and the data in the Supplier row will get mutated.
>
> Then lets say for example the next day we change the address that supplier was/is linked to, address gets added into history table, row gets mutated...
>
> But then the History Row of the updated supplier will still be pointing to the old address in the address table?

- isActive strategy

> This is also a strategy, in which I set fields that are current and valid, to isActive true, otherwise false. There is also a problem with this one: my supplier and customer tables are used for login. So I cannot just add a new row for changed data, because it is linked to the Primary Key, ID, and all other tables reference to this. So I need to change the original row, but then there is data loss.

I don't know what to do/try anymore, doees anybody have suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I like to start with two tables:

`Current` -- contains remaining inventory, counts, totals, etc.  This is `UPDATE`-heavy and has one row per entity.

`History` -- Transactions -- `INSERT`-only; many rows per entity.

The app does `SELECTs` from whichever one is appropriate.

`Current` could be derived from `History`, but that would be costly.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand. Could you please provide more info?
Also how is this different from my history table strategy and how does it solve it's problem?